# Django subclass that has a reference to instance of parent class

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to make a subclass that has a foreignkey to another instance of its parent class, for example for up-sampling.  I want to do this so that I can get a dropdown in a form that has a list of all the classes, regardless of whether it is based on another instance.

```
class ImageResolution(models.Model):
    image_depth = models.IntegerField(default=3)
    image_width = models.IntegerField(default=1920)
    image_height = models.IntegerField(default=1080)

class DerivedImageResolution(ImageResolution):
    base_resolution = models.ForeignKey(ImageResolution, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='base_resolution')
```

This throws an error:

```
imageapp.DerivedImageResolution.base_resolution: (models.E006) The field 'base_resolution' clashes with the field 'base_resolution' from model 'imageapp.imageresolution'.
```

Is it possible to do this?  If so, how can it be done?

Comment: Does your `ImageResolution` already has a field `BaseResolution?

Comment: no it does not.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this works, but changing the related name to something different than the subclass field name seems to fix this issue.

```
class ImageResolution(models.Model):
    image_depth = models.IntegerField(default=3)
    image_width = models.IntegerField(default=1920)
    image_height = models.IntegerField(default=1080)

class DerivedImageResolution(ImageResolution):
    base_resolution = models.ForeignKey(ImageResolution, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='orig_resolution')
```